# Get a raster domain as a shapefile without considering zeros (from all bands)?

Tags: arcpy, 3d-analyst

I have a raster file, and I want to check how much of my area is covered by the raster image - for this task I have generated RasterDomains, but it's considering the values (Zeros from all bands) for the conversion process. How to get the desired output with out considering the zeros?

```
 arcpy.RasterDomain_3d(inputraster, outputPoly, "POLYGON")
```

Here there is no option for avoiding zeros for not considering in the process of RasterDomians.

[image: Image shows the input Raster Image and, Output from RasterDomain and Desired Output as a shapefile]

Comment: Can I suggest to set the 'black' to null then use Raster to Polygon on an IsNull of your input image (aggregated by 5 or 10 can speed/clean things up at the cost of loosing accuracy), you should end up with something like your Desired Raster Domain except you will have a box around the edges and possibly quite a few speckles inside the image. Depending on what you're trying to do with the domain this might be what you need after removing the far outside box.

Comment: Is there any option for - editing the input raster image before sending it to RasterDomain_3d tool so that it will only consider the values other than Zeros from all bands.?

Comment: You could try Set Raster Properties http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000015z000000 to enforce 0,0..0 as NoData, according to the help http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q90000007s000000 *NoData cells are ignored in the output feature.*